# Zend Framework 2 Cache filesystem

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've been using the filesystem adapter for cacheing data.

E.g..

```
$cache = StorageFactory::factory(array(
    'adapter' => array(
    'name'    => 'filesystem'
    'options' => array('ttl' => 1800, 'cache_dir' => './data/cache'),
  ),
));
```

But when using the `getItem()` function AFTER the TTL clocks over it returns false on success etc, which it should... However, I've noticed that the file remains on the system. Is there a way of forcing the use of the cached file?

Scenario being.. My cache is outdated, when it runs some expensive functions they return nothing or it times out.. So I'd like to use the cache instead!

Just wondering if thats possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Don't use a TTL then?

Comment: If your Cache system recognize your files as outdated, it handles them like they are not cached. thats what TTL for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [useful link to the official ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#the-filesystem-adapter) for the specific StorageAdapter that you are using (filesystem).